# SaaS application on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, saas

I'm designing a `SAAS application`, which will be hosted on `AWS`. Previously I have used `Elastic Beanstalk` to manage applications. I could design the app so that all clients share single `DB` (that should be easy using `EB`). Is there a way to have a separate database for each client?
I could use environments for that (which doesn't seem to be a good idea since environments aren't meant for that), or create a separate beanstalk app for each client (I'm not sure if that wouldn't make updates more of a hassle).
I could also put EB aside and use different AWS services altogether.

My question is - can `EB` be used to create a multi-tenant `SAAS` app with isolated databases, or am I locked with a shared solution (single app, single db)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your customers are "come to my site, sign-up, start using", then build it as a single-app, using a single db. Design your database and app to be multi-tenant properly segregating data with built-in authorization checks.

If your SaaS architecture uses EB environments or databases based on customer, then:

1. You'll have to pay for resources **per customer**. That includes EC2 instances, RDS instances, etc.
2. When a customer signs-up, they'll need to wait for these resources to initialize. This delay may cause them to go elsewhere and not come back.
3. As your customer-base grows, so will your resources. Updates will take longer to apply.

I wouldn't consider a multi-tenant database architecture as being "locked in". I consider it "the right thing" as long as it's designed properly.

Comment: One more question if I may @Matt. If I would have to implement the isolated database architecture (or even one db/one app instance per client), could I achieve it with `Elastic Beanstalk` or should I rather use `CloudFormation`/`OpsWorks` (I'm not familiar with neither)?
I'm afraid that client might be reluctant to embrace the fully shared model (for security reasons mostly).

Comment: If you really MUST seperate the databases.  How about seperate database tables in the same server?  Different credentials for each client as well.  More like 'shared hosting'

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk uses CloudFormation under the hood. Either would work if you needed to keep the databases separated.